# Suppose that $ A^p = I_n $, show that $ (A-I_n)^p = 0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, prime-numbers

Let $A\in M_n({\Bbb F}_p )$. Suppose that $A^p = I_n$. Show that$(A-I_n)^p = 0$, and $A$ has an eigenvector $v\in {\Bbb F}^n_p$ with eigenvalue 1.

I know that $p$ divides the binomial coefficient $(^p_i)$ for $1\leq i\leq p-1$.
But what is the next?

Thnaks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for *odd* primes. Since $\;A,\,I\;$ commute (over any field), you can use the binomial theorem (as with *any* pair of commuting square matrices over any field):

$$(A-I)^p=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom pk(-1)^k A^k=I-A^p=0\;,\;\;\text{since $p$ is odd}$$

The above is just the same with get for element in $\;\Bbb F_p\;:\;\;(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$

For $\;p=2\;$ is mostly the same, but remember that then $\;1=-1\;$ so if you want you can dispose of all the minus signs...